# Mapping two different columns in SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, join, left-join

Hi Wonder if someone can help me with this query. I have a data set within which I have two columns. Column A/Column B; lets call it Table UpdateData.

There are also two Access tables with standing data that are mapping tables for these codes. One table is pre-update codes (oldCodes) and the other is post-system update codes (NewCode). In my data set Column A has pre-update codes and column B has post-update codes. My idea was to combine these two Access tables new and old codes into one table in SQL Server (2005) like this To Create Table combinedCodes:

```
Oldcode    display 
=====     =======
RTYX45    No
GHYUN6    No
BYUER5    Yes

Newcode    display 
=====      =======
VUJNG6     Yes
LERWS8     No
XCRYU7     Yes

code      display 
=====     =======
RTYX45    No
GHYUN6    No
BYUER5    Yes
VUJNG6    Yes
LERWS8    No
XCRYU7    Yes
```

Note this is only an example of data and there is a lot more rows than is displayed.

So if I join updateData and Combined codes how do I set it so that one field (display) can show the match from either column A/B (or not). When I joined on only one column lets say Column A with left join to my updateData table from combinedCodes table I got the correct data in my combinedCodes display field and nulls for the ones that didn't match.

But then I introduced another join from Column B using left join to my UpdateData table from CombinedCodes and the combinedCodes display showed Old Codes where before nulls were, which I would want, but also showed old codes where before the new codes were used. I was getting a bit mixed up with what was actually happening so this might not be 100% right however when comparing each query result with individual join the query results with the joins to column A and Column B was different although same count of data when adding up individual count from separate queries.

```
select c.Fields
--,f.Display
,pt.Display
 from UpdateData c 
INNER JOIN PRE_CODES pt
ON c.columnA = pt.code -- only for pre-codes
--INNER JOIN POST_CODES f
--ON c.columnB = f.code
```

The join and field commented out are for the post-codes and the other is for pre-codes. If i include left outer join to show nulls for post-codes then introduce 2nd join and f.display plus left join for field it doesn't show the same results as if I run each individually and combine them.

this kind of join is going beyond my understanding of joins and I do not know exactly what I should do here so over to any of you who can help me with this

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I can see a couple of options.

One is to write two queries, one for each code table (with an inner join in each case so you don't have any nulls), and then use [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) to combine the results and generate the data for the combined table.

The other is to write a single query that joins to each table with a left outer join, which will result in one column that has either a value or a null for one table, and another column that has either a value or a null for the other table.  Then add another column to the results that uses [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) to combine those two columns into a single non-null column.

Comment: Hey, +1 for a much better answer than the usual over-literal join writeup! Good question, too.

Comment: @JacobM of course (hits forehead with palm of hand) a union is a really good option! Not used SQL for a while and totally forgot about that! Your other option was half way to what I was doing but you have provided a solution for displaying each column result separately then combining them. On top of that I also was trying to understand the logic/approach of two joins to the same table/displaying results in one column it's not something I have had to do at all so it's an interesting problem.